How to talk to my boyfriend about not liking insta pics
I’m newly in a relationship (6 months together), and in the very beginning my boyfriend and I talked about how we feel about Instagram while in relationships. We both agreed it can be a slippery slope & unnecessary drama that can breed mistrust and insecurities in a relationship.
In addition, we’ve talked throughout our time together that we both agreed to unfollow anyone we’d been sexually attracted to, been intimate with, dated, or even just found attractive, (and still seemingly in agreement about Instagram boundaries) kind of as a means to go all in and to create and officiate that boundary.
But this hasn’t stopped him from following new females over the months and his most recent follow (they’re following each other) he’s liked her photos.
We’ve been down this road before and I feel so disrespected and that he is up to no good if we’ve already discussed this and he knows it bothers me.
I’m not on his insta in pics at all, only one photo with some of his family in it so you can’t even tell we’re together. He also won’t reshare my stories I post of us and it’s starting to feel like I’m being hidden away so he can play or something.
How can I healthily approach this issue and conversation with him? I don’t want this to break us, but I’m constantly feeling horrible by his actions. I also realize it makes me look like a creep on his insta and I don’t want him to think I’m unhinged. I didn’t used to care, but over time it’s really started to breed insecurity, especially since this new situation (4 days ago).
How can I address these concerns with him?

To avoid getting answers stating things you've already tried or considered: What have you tried, or thought of trying, to address this in a 'healthy' way, which of your interpersonal skills have you already been using? What part of your interpersonal skills do you think you need to change to have a healthy conversation about this?

Please y'all with the power to do so, vote to reopen this, it has enough details and certainly doesn't deserve to be closed.

I have something I would like to see in the TS: Why is this an issue, why does it make you insecure? (most) Man like looking at women, maybe even a small spicy thought, but in 99% of the cases that is all it is and forget about her 10sec later (not even joking). If you focus on real life, what is missing there that leaves room for insecurity about something like this?
